# Angular: Show Component within Popup

Tags: angular, angular-material, popup

I have a `PopupComponent` (within a Angular Library) with some Input variables that I'm using like this:

```
<lib-popup
    [popupHeight] = "popupHeight"
    [popupWidth] = "popupWidth"
    [popupPositionX] = "popupPositionX"
    [popupPositionY] = "popupPositionY"
  >
</lib-popup>
```

Now I want to insert for example my `MapComponent` into that Popup, so that when I open the popup, it shows a Map.

I added another input variable `contentComponent` like this:

```
  <lib-popup
    [popupHeight] = "popupHeight"
    [popupWidth] = "popupWidth"
    [popupPositionX] = "popupPositionX"
    [popupPositionY] = "popupPositionY"
    [contentComponent] = "GeomapComponent"
  >
  </lib-popup>
```

My `popup.component.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { PopupContentDefaultComponent } from './popup.content.default.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() popupPositionX = ''; // use default (px)
  @Input() popupPositionY = ''; // use default (px)
  @Input() popupHeight = '400px';
  @Input() popupWidth = '600px';
  @Input() popupOpen = false;
  @Input() popupClose = false;
  @Input() contentComponent = PopupContentDefaultComponent;

  private dialogRef!: any;
  private dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // set config values for popup
    this.dialogConfig.height = this.popupHeight;
    this.dialogConfig.width = this.popupWidth;
    this.dialogConfig.position = {
      left: this.popupPositionX,
      top: this.popupPositionY
    };

    if (this.popupOpen) {
      this.openDialog();
    }

    if (this.popupClose) {
      this.closeDialog();
    }
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.contentComponent, this.dialogConfig);
    console.log('Popup has been opened.');
  }

  closeDialog(): void {
    if (this.dialogRef) {
      this.dialogRef.close();
      console.log('Popup has been closed.');
    } else {
      console.log('There is no popup to close.');
    }
  }

}
```

Until now, everything works just fine! A popup will open which contains my `MapComponent`.

#### Now the problem:

I want to add a close button to my popup which is always there, no matter which content component I insert into the popup.
So I think I need an additional component, something like `PopupContentComponent` which holds the button and some other stuff that each popup should contain, and which also has a placeholder for the component that I want to show.

But how do I do this in Angular?

I don't want to change the `MapComponent` and the Popup Component should stay within my library.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you need just to close popup with that button? Why not adding button <div (click)="fun()"></div>  into HTML part of popup component and also *ngIf. When button is pressed function would than add true to some variable and than you define <div *ngIf="!showMe">your components<div> and than you add function into your component fun()= {showMe=true;}. Also don't forget to define it in component up like showMe:boolean = false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PopupComponent` relies on `MatDialog` to show the pop-up with the component reference passed to it as `contentComponent` input binding.

`MatDialog` is merely a portal container and does not have its own body.
Hence as you rightly said, you will need to create a `PopupContentComponent` which will have the default controls like the `close` button.

The `PopupContentComponent` can always project the passed in component Eg. `MapComponent` using `ng-content`.

This way your `PopupComponent` (using `MatDialog`) will always show `PopupContentComponent` which displays the required default controls and the child component (eg.`MapComponent`) using `ng-content`.

Also, you would be required to add the `PopupContentComponent` to your modules list of `entryComponents`.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds good. But how do I pass the MapComponent which I get via @Input within the PopupComponent to the PopupContentComponent so that it can be displayed?

Comment: There are two ways:


1. Pass the `MapComponent` as data property to `MatDialog`. This will make the `MapComponent` available to the `PopupContentComponent` via `data` property.


2. You can explore `dynamic components` with Angular, where you instantiate a component at runtime using `ComponentResolver`


I would suggest option #1 as it is much easier and testable.

Comment: I used option 1 and <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="data"></ng-container> and it works like a charm. Thank you so much!